# Twitter app that also posts to Facebook, intelligently

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there a twitter app that also posts to facebook, but does it intelligently? Like instead of posting the link with the post, it attaches the link to the post (while posting to facebook). And Uploads pic to the wall instead of just posting the tweetpic link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get an app on Facebook that will grab your Twitter feed.  That's what I do and it does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 5):

Seesmic and TweetDeck are good for spamming updates. If you use Foursquare or PicPlz these both post the "intelligent" version of the checkin or picture to Facebook while doing the normal text + link with Twitter.

Comment: PicPlz is shutting down as of July 3.

Answer (score 0):

Seesmic
Well designed, good for Facebook, Twitter and Buzz.